# If a user has_many cars, and a car has_many appointments, how can I get all of a users appointments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am using Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1.

A user `has_many` cars, and a car `has_many` appointments. What is the easiest way to get all of a users appointments?

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this: `user.cars.appointments`, and I know I can do something like:

```
user.cars.each do |car|
  appointments = []
  car.appointments.each do |app|
    appointments >> app
  end
  return appointments
end
```

but I was hoping there was a quicker, more "Rails" way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [has_many :through assocation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) in ActiveRecord.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_many :cars
  has_many :appointments, through: :cars

end
```

The you can get all the appointments for a user with:

```
@user.appointments
```

This will automatically build the INNER JOIN SQL needed to link the appointments to users via the cars table.